# What happens when Kalman filter is applied on a memoryless system?

Tags: estimation, kalman-filters, bayesian-estimation

I'm trying to set up a Kalman filter for my system

$$ x_{k+1} = f(u_k) $$
$$ z_{k+1} = g(x_{k+1}) $$

and found that while the filter "works" (able to reduce rmse from 1.5% in the open loop model to 0.9%), the performance doesn't seem to be affected by the covariances settings (P, Q, R) at all. I tried setting them to anywhere between 1e-10 to 1e10 and nothing seemed to change.

I tried to change the system to
$$ x_{k+1} = \tfrac12 x_k + \tfrac12f(x_k) $$

which is a crude way of forcing the current state to relate to previous state, and found that the filter is now affected by the covariance. However, this setup makes no physical sense and produced a much higher error (about 3%).

I'm trying to understand intuitively what the implication is of having states that only relate to input and not previous states, and why that makes the covariances useless?

Comment: @PeterK. Sorry that was a typo! It should be f(u) where u is the input. I will fix it when I'm on desktop!

Comment: OK!   It sounds like the system is a memoryless system. So it just depends on the current input.  That's not going to be helped much by a Kalman filter, I suspect, if there is no state history to be useful.

Comment: @PeterK. Why would the filter still reduce the error from the open loop model though?

Comment: Do you have a model for the system? If the system model doesn't include state dependence, then why try to make it have state dependence?

Comment: @PeterK. Yes the system model was a empirical relationship derived between the state & another variable. While the state is decreasing from previous states, this is embedded into the f(u) relationship, so I couldn't come up with an explicit x_k+1 = f(x_k) relatinoship.

Comment: OK, so don't force it. If your system model doesn't have state dependence, go with that.

Comment: Your system, as you describe it, boils down to $z(k+1) = g(f(u(k)))$.  This does have memory in a sense -- today's measurement depends on yesterday's input -- but unless you're making independent measurements of $u(k)$ and $z(k)$ then the memory is meaningless, and there should be no way of reducing noise.  If you _are_ making those independent measurements, and your problem is set up correctly, then $\mathbf Q$ and $\mathbf R$ _should_ matter -- but the filter would be trivial.  Please expand the question to show (preferably by difference equations) what calculations you're actually using.